# Estimating the false positive rate for a strictly standardized mean difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

Does anyone have a good source that clearly explains how to estimate the false positive rate or restricted false positive rate of the strictly standardized mean difference (SSMD)? I am trying to follow this [paper](http://jbx.sagepub.com/content/12/5/645.long) but getting lost.

Thanks